# Golang : process took too long. Implementing Spell Checker

Tags: arrays, algorithm, memory-management, go

http://play.golang.org/p/H5E0ExL85d

I've implemented some Peter Norvig's spelling check algorithm with Go.

It's weird that the ***FIRST THREE*** calling works correct giving me the desired output.

**But from the second, it is saying "process took too long."**

Could anybody look at my code and tell what goes wrong?

Here's the snippet that is possibly going wrong.

Everything works perfect with the same code in English version.

UNICODE format and boundary have changed according to language because English contain 1 byte per alphabet and Asian languages in this case contain 3 bytes per one character.

This is trying to run the same Algorithm as the one for English that was working perfect.
But this is NOT working.

```
total_set := []string{}
for _, elem := range splits {

    if len(elem.str2) > 3 {
        //deletion
        total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+elem.str2[3:])

        //replace
        for i:=0; i<len(koreanletter)/3; i++ {
            total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(koreanletter[3*i:3*(i+1)])+elem.str2[3:])
        }

        //transpose
        if len(elem.str2) > 9 {
            total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(elem.str2[3:6])+string(elem.str2[:3])+elem.str2[9:])
        }

    } else {
        //deletion
        total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1)
    }

    //insertion
    for _, c := range koreanletter {
        total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(c)+elem.str2)
    }
    return RemoveDuplicateStringArrayForKorean(total_set)
}
```

---

The one for English is below.
This is working perfect.

```
//Edits1 is to measure the distance between strings.
func (model *Model) Edits1(word string) []string {
  const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

  splits := []Pair{}
  for i := 0; i <= len(word); i++ {
    splits = append(splits, Pair{word[:i], word[i:]})
  }

  total_set := []string{}
  for _, elem := range splits {

    if len(elem.str2) > 0 {
      //deletion
      total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+elem.str2[1:])

      //replace
      for _, c := range alphabet {
        total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(c)+elem.str2[1:])
      }

      //transpose
      if len(elem.str2) > 1 {
        total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(elem.str2[1])+string(elem.str2[0])+elem.str2[2:])
      }

    } else {
      //deletion
      total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1)
    }

    //insertion
    for _, c := range alphabet {
      total_set = append(total_set, elem.str1+string(c)+elem.str2)
    }
  }
  return RemoveDuplicateStringArrayLowerCase(total_set)
}
```

**Addition: ordered arguments and now I have three things working.**

**None of the characters are missing from the koreanletter.**

**Is there anyway that I can see the error more specifically? I just can't figure out.**

Comment: The playground is pretty strict with running time. If one programs takes a picosecond to long it will be terminated.

Comment: I think there may be something missing from the `koreanletter` constant. Certain strings are working and certain others aren't. Working strings: "캄사합니다", "중하생" and "아벼지". The others are getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks. And nothing is missing from koreanletter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing around with your code, it seems it is your `KoreanKnownEdits2` which is taking too long. In your forth example (the one failing), the length of `model.KoreanEdits1(input_word)` is `28197` and the length of the first `model.KoreanEdits1(elem1)` is `23499`, which makes around 662 millions cases to try. It seems the program is failing after the first 147 thousands, because it takes too long ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MGRLzpz_qK)).

Any examples which did not required a call to `KoreanKnownEdits2` seem to work, so I suspect you should rewrite this function to avoid the exhaustive search, or at least limit it to a more reasonable size if you want to use it with the playground's time limit. I haven't studied your code in enough details to be 100% certain of that, but I suspect the 26 letters of western alphabet make it manageable for the English version, while the extended Korean alphabet makes the size of your input too large to be processed on the playground's time limit, regardless of the number of bytes each character is encoded with.